# How can I know that my iPhone is connected to the Apple Push Notification Service?

Tags: iphone

How can I know that my iPhone is connected to the Apple Push Notification Service? Is there any way that I can see it in my iPhone?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
```

method, you can use this code:

```
if( !application.enabledRemoteNotificationTypes )
    {
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Home screen UI: Settings/Notifications, set to On/Off.

Though as this is a programming forum, what is it you're trying to do, or trying to determine?