# How can I generate a device token used for Apple push notification?

Tags: iphone

how to generate device token used for apple push for a particular application for that device for a user

Comment: You've asked at least five very similar questions about this lately: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523824/apple-push-notification-service , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598723/apple-push-notification-service , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537329/register-device-at-run-time , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519626/is-it-possible-to-make-certificate-through-code-for-apple-push-notification-servi , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477060/how-can-i-know-that-my-iphone-is-connected-to-the-apple-push-notification-service .

Comment: Perhaps you should just clean up the wording in one of them in order to get a better response.

Answer (score 4):

The following document outlines most of the APNS functionality. Including howto generate a device token.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/RemoteNotificationsPG.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Below delegate method write in app delegate method

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
  }